# How to choose some items from array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have an original list of sites:

```
original_list = ["http://www.firstSite.com", "http://secondSite.com", "http://thirdSite.com", "http://www.fourthSite.com"]
```

I want to allow user to choose some sites and arrange the new array like this:

```
new_list = ["http://secondSite.com", "http://www.fourthSite.com"]
```

The filling of the new array depends on user's choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. It takes the input and inserts it into a new array:

```
original_list = ["http://www.firstSite.com", "http://secondSite.com", "http://thirdSite.com", "http://www.fourthSite.com"]
new_array = input("Choose some sites from %s. Separate each website by a space " % (original_list)).split()

for site in new_array: #Checking if the sites entered by user are in the original_list
    if site not in original_list:
        print ("Error!")
```

You can also use the index of a site to ask the user for input. Like this:

```
original_list = ["http://www.firstSite.com", "http://secondSite.com", "http://thirdSite.com", "http://www.fourthSite.com"]
user_input = input("Enter the indices of the websites in %s you choose separated by a space " % (original_list)).split()
new_array = [original_list[x] for x in user_input]

for site in new_array: #Checking if the sites entered by user are in the original_list
    if site not in original_list:
        print ("Error!")
```

Both of these will create a list containing the sites that the user selected.

It's hard to give you a clear solution as you don't provide what you are trying to accomplish. So, let me know if this works for you and if it doesn't, I'm happy to delete my answer.

Comment: You should consider the case where user inputs an item not in the `original_list`.

Comment: @theausome sure will edit. thanks a lot

Comment: It's for clarifying of which sites will be scraped. Your solution works, thanks

Comment: @Anton I just added some code to consider the case where user inputs an item not in the original list. No problem and good luck with whatever you're making.